# how i can get a Bit from a register?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

In the code, you can see that there is register of state ( reg [N-1] State).  i want to access the 10 bits of state in 10 different signal or register or we can say wires.  how is this possible. ??
i used assign statement but i want to make a logic for clock.
This gives an error

Line 33: Syntax error near "<="

```
module Genes_Network #( 
                    N =10     // 
                            )  
                    ( input Clock ,
                      input Reset ,
            //                input reg [N-1:0] Satein,
                      output reg [N-1 : 0] State_Gene                                  
);
 reg    [N-1:0] State ; 
 reg    Fgf8,Emx2, Pax6,Coup_tfi,Sp8;  // Genes 
 reg    F,E,P,C,S ;                    // Proteins
 // 
  Fgf8    <= State[9] ;
  F       <= State[N-2] ;
  E       <= State[N-4] ;
  Pax6    <= State[N-5] ;
  Emx2    <= State[N-3] ;
  P       <= State[N-6] ;
  Coup_tfi<= State[N-7] ;
  C       <= State[N-8] ;
  Sp8     <= State[N-8] ;
  S       <= State[N-9] ;    
 always @(posedge Clock )

 //Network LOgic 
  Fgf8    <=  F & (~E) & S; 
 endmodule
```

Comment: Fgf8    <= State[9] ;

Answer (score 0):

When you're designing combo logic, you should use `assign` and blocking assignment (`=`), i.e.:

```
assign Fgf8 = State[9];
```

Nonblocking assignments (`<=`) should be used only in a clocked `always` block, i.e.:

```
always @(posedge Clock)
  Fgf8 <=  F & (~E) & S;
```

One other thing, remember that you can't drive the same signal (in this case `Fgf8`) in two different places.

Comment: Target <Fgf8> of concurrent assignment or output port connection should be a net type.   No i am getting this error.  i know the this is error. but how i can do this thing @ Qiu

Comment: @Misal313: first of all, you have to decide if you drive it as combo or sequential logic. If you drive as combo - `Fgf8` should be defined as `wire`. PS in SystemVerilog you can simply use `logic` instead of `wire` and `reg` keywords.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax error is that you can only assign nets or variables as part of a concurrent assignment statement (`assign`) or a procedural statement (`always`, `initial`, etc.).  Simply putting

```
var <= value;
```

out on its own is a syntax error.  In the case of your example the best solution would probably be to change the `reg` declarations to `wire`, and then do

```
assign Fgf8    = State[9] ;
assign F       = State[N-2] ;
// etc.
```

You could also probably do something along the lines of

```
always @(State)
begin
    Fgf8    = State[9] ;
    F       = State[N-2] ;
    // etc.
end
```

however I seem to recall that the sensitivity list ( `@(State)` ) may be trickier with vectors than that (like it might need to be broken down into `@( State[9] or @State[8] or @State[7] or ...)` to work properly).  I've been using SystemVerilog exclusively for a number of years now so I don't recall that detail for certain.  This is another area where SystemVerilog could help out -- one can use SV's `always_comb` instead of `always` for combinatorial logic and skip the explicit sensitivity list altogether.

In your simple case you might be able to get away with the nonblocking assignments (`<=`) with no harm but it's not recommended.  All the rest of @Qiu's comments also apply and you should take note of them as well.